# How to join held Lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, hold

Let's say I have

```
 a = Hold@{2+2} 
 b = Hold@{4+4}
```

How can I get

> ```
> Hold@{2+2,4+4}
> ```

ie join the two held lists ?

More generally I'm looking for a way to be able to do operations on such held lists, like being able to have `Dimensions` or `Length`, being able to `Prepend` or `Append` (answering this question would allow this) or change some parts of such lists easily.

Comment: One way would be `Thread[Join[a, b]] /. {Hold[x___]} :> Hold[{x}]`.

Comment: @Leonid As with everyone else you seem to have forgotten the case where the lists in `a` and `b` are not the same length.  Or perhaps that's why you didn't post this as an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not "like anyone else" - I proudly claim to be the first person here to make this mistake :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering the question at face value, you might use:

```
a = Hold@{1 + 1, 2 + 2};

b = Hold@{4 + 4};

Sequence @@@ Join[a, b] /. h_@x__ :> h@{x}
```

> ```
> Hold[{1 + 1, 2 + 2, 4 + 4}]
> ```

Answer (score 8):

I think there is a case to be made for not using `List` at all.  It seems to me that it is a needless complication.  Why not instead use `Hold` *in place of* `List`?

```
a = Hold[2 + 2];
b = Hold[4 + 4];

c = Join[a, b]

Append[c, Unevaluated[6 + 6]]
```

> ```
> Hold[2 + 2, 4 + 4]
>
> Hold[2 + 2, 4 + 4, 6 + 6]
> ```

Also:

```
x = Hold @@ {a, b}

Length[x]

Dimensions[x]
```

> ```
> Hold[Hold[2 + 2], Hold[4 + 4]]
>
> 2
>
> {2, 1}
> ```

Isn't that much cleaner?  Where does it fail you?

Comment: This is cleaner indeed and was aware of this way. I happened to need for manipulating expressions before expanding them in this context http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24596/66, and the idea seemed interesting to me. But I guess I'll have to adapt my code. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Faysal I glanced at the answer you referenced and I'll admit I don't understand it yet.  Could you summarize your need for `Hold[{...}]` and why that seems more natural than Hold without List?

Answer (score 6):

One easy way, which does not work for lists of different length, is

```
a = Hold[{2 + 2}];
b = Hold[{4 + 4}];   
Thread[{a, b} /. Hold[{a___}] :> Hold[a], Hold]
```

What happens here is the following: first, you can use

```
{a, b} /. Hold[{a___}] :> Hold[a]
```

to get rid of the inner list braces without evaluating your expressions. Since we use `{a,b}` we will already get the final joined list. The only problem is that the `Hold`'s are inside. For this, we use `Thread` to turn it inside out.

As pointed out by Mr.Wizard, the approach fails when the list are of different length. For such a case you could use

```
a = Hold[{1 + 1, 2 + 2}];
b = Hold[{4 + 4}];
Flatten[{a, b} /. List :> Hold, 2, Hold] /. Hold[expr__] :> Hold[{expr}]
```

Comment: This fails if the lists are not the same length, e.g. `a = Hold[{1 + 1, 2 + 2}]; b = Hold[{4 + 4}];`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You really have to try everything, right? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If the lists are of length 1 as in the example, you can use this:

```
Thread[{a, b}, Hold][[{1}, All, 1]]
```

For longer lists there is this:

```
Thread[Join @@ Thread /@ {a, b}, Hold]
```

Comment: This fails if the lists are not length one, e.g. `a = Hold@{1 + 1, 2 + 2}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, good point.

Comment: Finally an answer I can vote for. :D

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you. I shall now delete the notebook of shame and pretend like this was the most obvious thing that sprang to mind.

Comment: Hahaha :-)  I tried several that failed before realizing I could use `Sequence` since the example is `Hold` and not `HoldComplete`.  Yours however would work even if it were, with minor change.  For `HoldComplete` I had this bit of nasty I decided not to post: `Join[a, b] /. H_[h_[x___], h_[y___]] :> H[h[x, y]]`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit2**:Coping with my habit of missing subtleties I have tried again to correct it further.

```
Block[{a = Hold@{2 + 2}, b = Hold@{4 + 4}, 
  l}, {l = HoldForm[Hold[{ {s}, {d}}]] /. {s -> a /. Hold -> Defer, 
       d -> b /. Hold -> Defer}; Length[l]}
   Table[l[[i]] /. List -> Sequence, {i, 1, Length[l]}] /. 
  HoldPattern[Hold[x___]] :> Hold[{x}]
```

> {Hold[{Sequence[2+2],Sequence[4+4]}]}

To check with @Mr.Wizard's test case of unequal lists, I am getting following output.

```
Block[{a = Hold@{2 + 2, 1 + 1}, b = Hold@{4 + 4}, 
  l}, {l = HoldForm[Hold[{{s}, {d}}]] /. {s -> a /. Hold -> Defer, 
       d -> b /. Hold -> Defer}; Length[l]} Table[
    l[[i]] /. List -> Sequence, {i, 1, Length[l]}] /. 
  HoldPattern[Hold[x___]] :> Hold[{x}]]
```

> {Hold[{Sequence[2 + 2, 1 + 1], Sequence[4 + 4]}]}
>      `ReleaseHold` gives {4,2,8}.

Comment: The problem is that your expression only *looks* as your approach works. Use `FullForm` to see everything. (Beside, that thing Kuba mentioned)

Comment: yes yes..m looking into it now.Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

A way that is quite manual but could be an inspiration for other related operations.

```
ReleaseAllHold[expr_,firstLevel_:0,lastLevel_:Infinity] := 
 Replace[expr, 
  (Hold|HoldForm|HoldPattern|HoldComplete)[e___] :> e, 
  {firstLevel, lastLevel}, 
  Heads -> True
 ];

JoinHeldLists[heldLists__Hold]:=
Module[{a,b,c,d},
    a={heldLists};
    b=Map[Hold,a,{1,-2}];
    c=ReleaseAllHold[b,0,-4];
    d=Join@@c;
    With[{dd=d},
        ReleaseAllHold[Hold@dd,1]
    ]
];

JoinHeldLists[Hold@{2+2},Hold@{4+4}]
```