# Operations on expressions within Hold

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation, hold

I want to convert `{Hold[1 + 2], Hold[3 + 4], Hold[5*6]}` into `Hold[{1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5*6}]`.

I have tried

```
{Hold[1 + 2], Hold[3 + 4],  Hold[5*6]} /. {Hold[a_], Hold[b_], Hold[c_]} -> Hold[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> Hold[{1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 6}]
> ```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Related (perhaps duplicate): [Join held lists](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32119/how-to-join-held-lists), [Injecting `Sequence` into `Hold`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression).

Comment: It's a shame this question was closed as a duplicate. I would use: `Distribute[{Hold[1 + 2], Hold[3 + 4], Hold[5*6]}, Hold]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll what's the benefit of `Distribute` over `Thread` there?

Comment: @CarlWoll I must be missing something.  Wouldn't your answer be equally valid to [(32119)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32119/121)?  Why reopen this one rather than answering that one?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I wanted to discuss the step in this question in a bit more detail, that is the {__Hold} -> Hold[_List] transformation. In question 32119, this transformation can be used as one piece of an answer, but there are many answers that don't use this transformation at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Join` works with every `Head` so it seems to be the best way here:

```
Join @@ {Hold[1 + 2], Hold[3 + 4], Hold[5*6]}
```

> ```
> Hold[1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 6]
> ```

and if you really need those `{}` inside:

```
% /. Hold[x__] :> Hold[{x}]
```

> ```
> Hold[{1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 6}]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

One way which works no matter how many elements your list has is to use [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html)

```
expr = {Hold[1 + 2], Hold[3 + 4], Hold[5*6]};
Flatten[Hold @@ expr, 1, Hold]

(* Hold[1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 6] *)
```

You see that the list braces are not created. They could be reconstructed too but the question is whether you really need them. I assume for your purpose it is not really a difference whether you have `List[e1,e2,...]` or `Hold[e1,e2,...]` but `Hold` has the advantage of not evaluating your expression.

If you want the list, you can add another rule

```
expr /. {a__Hold} :> Flatten[Hold[a], 1, Hold] /. 
 Hold[a__] :> Hold[{a}]

(* Hold[{1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 6}] *)
```

Or you define a function which basically does the same but the rules are hidden in the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html)

```
f[{a__}] := f[a];
f[a__Hold] := f[Flatten[Hold[a], 1, Hold]];
f[Hold[a__]] := Hold[{a}];

f[expr]

(* Hold[{1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 6}] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple direct ways of doing this are to use [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread) and [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute).

```
Thread[{Hold[1 + 2], Hold[3 + 4],  Hold[5*6]}, Hold]
Distribute[{Hold[1 + 2], Hold[3 + 4],  Hold[5*6]}, Hold]
```

> Hold[{1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 6}]
>
> Hold[{1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 6}]

The problem with [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute) is that it distributes, so if the [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold) objects have more than one argument, you will get probably unwanted distribution.

```
Distribute[{Hold[1+2, x], Hold[3+4], Hold[5+6]}, Hold]
```

> Hold[{1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 + 6}, {x, 3 + 4, 5 + 6}]

On the other hand, the nice thing about [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute) is that you can stick in arbitrary heads:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
Distribute[{Hold[1+2], Hold[3+4], Hold[5*6]}, Hold, List, f, g]
```

> f[g[1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 6]]

Just like [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute), [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread) may not work as desired when the [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold) objects have more than one argument:

```
Thread[{Hold[1 + 2, x], Hold[3 + 4],  Hold[5*6]}, Hold]
```

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {Hold[1+2,x],Hold[3+4],Hold[5 6]} cannot be combined.
>
> {Hold[1 + 2, x], Hold[3 + 4], Hold[5 6]}

```
Thread[{Hold[1 + 2, x], Hold[3 + 4, y], Hold[5*6, z]}, Hold]
```

> Hold[{1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 6}, {x, y, z}]

Finally, [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread) has support for a 3rd argument, although I don't think I've ever used it:

```
Thread[{Hold[1+2, x], Hold[3 + 4], Hold[5*6]}, Hold, 1]
```

> Hold[{1 + 2, Hold[3 + 4], Hold[5 6]}, {x, Hold[3 + 4], Hold[5 6]}]

Summarizing, I find [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute) and [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread) useful when working with [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold) objects.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting way:

```
expr = {Hold[1 + 2], Hold[3 + 4], Hold[5*6]};
expr /. {Hold -> Sequence, List -> Hold}
```

> Hold[1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 6]

And if you want the inner `List` back:

```
expr /. {Hold -> Sequence, List -> Hold} /. Hold[x__] :> Hold[{x}]
```

> ```
> Hold[{1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 6}]
> ```