# How to stop a single function to be evaluated?

Tags: evaluation

See this example:

```
AA = {x} \[Function] Normalize[x]
BB = {x} \[Function] Evaluate[AA[x]*5]
```

I need BB to be Normalize[x]*5.

Some context:I call evaluate because I'm using CForm later to do some optimizations, so my functions need not to call other user-defined functions which would translate into something that is not really valid C code.

Normalize though just evaluates to a version which makes some sense only for complex numbers, this is not what the definition of Normalize does... Also, afaik Evaluate doesn't take assumptions, so I don't know how to "hint" it not to incorrectly expand Normalize...

I've tried various hold/replace/single step evaluate tricks, all not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding code generation, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214946/how-to-dynamically-generate-mathematica-code/6215394#6215394) I described a generalization of a technique presented in one of the answers, which might be relevant.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
AA[x_] := Normalize[x];
Hold[BB[x_] := 5 AA[x]] /. DownValues[AA] // ReleaseHold

??BB
```

[image]

Comment: Great stuff as usual, but you don't need the `Hold`/`ReleaseHold` pair; `Unevaluated` will do: `Unevaluated[BB[x_] := 5 AA[x]] /. DownValues[AA]`

Answer (score 2):

Using the function ExpandCode defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24596/66), you can expand any code that you want, for example expand all functions which name consist in upper case letters.

```
AA[x_] := Normalize[x];  
ExpandCode@Hold[Bb[x_] := 5 AA[x]] // ReleaseHold
Bb // DownValues
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need BB to be  Normalize[x]*5 explicitly, then use

```
AA[x_] := Normalize[x]

BBtemp[x_] := 5*AA[x]

BB[x_] = Hold[BBtemp[x]] /. DownValues[BBtemp] /. DownValues[AA]

(*Hold[5 Normalize[x]]*)
```

Unfortunately, when you act by `ReleaseHold` on it, it becomes `5 x/Norm[x]`.

Comment: That's the struggle, I can Hold but that will mean that CForm will contain the Hold which will then again screw my code-generator... I guess I could define a Hold function in the C preprocessor that just ignores the Hold though... Mhm...