# Compile function which calls other functions to C

Tags: compile

I have a function which calls other functions and I would like to compile it to C code. For example:

```
foo[p_] := 0.7 Exp[-p^2]
f[a_, n_] := 
 Module[{s, p, i}, s = 0; p = a; 
  For[i = 0, i < n, i++, s += foo[p]; p *= a;]; s]
```

Now if I do

```
cf = Compile[{{a, _Real}, {n, _Integer}}, f[a, n]]
```

and print the C code with

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[cf]
```

the output is

```
R1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[f][ R0, I0]]
```

which is obviously not desired.

When I try `Compile[{{a, _Real}, {n, _Integer}}, Evaluate@f[a, n]]`, it just gives a function which returns 0...

Comment: Have a look at my answer here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24595/66 , it does what you want with the function CompileExpand and if the names of the user functions called are defined with upper cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to inject the body of your function definition(s) into the `Compile` call without evaluating it. One possibility is (I had to change your `Module` a bit to correct a type error)

```
foo[p_] := 0.7 Exp[-p^2]
f[a_, n_] := Module[{s = 0.0, p = a, i},
  For[i = 0, i < n, i++, s += foo[p]; p *= a;]; s]

cf = ReleaseHold[Hold[Compile[{{a, _Real}, {n, _Integer}}, f[a, n]]] 
       /. DownValues[f] /. DownValues[foo]]
```

#### More explanation

First of all you need to understand that when you make a function definintion, *Mathematica* stores a *replacement rule*. There are different kinds of such rules and the most important ones are `DownValues` and `OwnValues`. `OwnValues` are used when you make assignments like `x=1` or `x:=1`. `DownValues` are for function definitions. Let take a look at the rules of `foo`

```
DownValues[foo]
(* {HoldPattern[foo[p_]] :> 0.7 Exp[-p^2]} *)
```

Very sloppy speaking, when you make any calculation in *Mathematica* then it looks at your code and checks what rules are connected with a symbol. Then it uses these rules and makes the replacement, if the pattern matches.

In your case, the problem with your `Compile` call is that

1. `Compile` has the attribute `HoldAll` which prevents that `f[a,n]` is replaced with its definition.
2. If you force the evaluation of the expression `f[a,n]` using `Evaluate` then it does too much, because it doesn't only insert the definition body of `f` (the `Module` part) but it evaluates it right away. This is not good because at this point, you don't have numeric values for `a` and `n` and therefore, the `For` loop doesn't do anything at all.

At this point, it is clear what you want: You have made a definition for `f[a,n]`, how can you get the fully expanded function body? Two ingredients: First, you use the *definition rules* (`DownValues`) by yourself and second, you prevent the evaluation using `Hold`. There you go..

```
Hold[f[a, n]] /. DownValues[f]
(* Hold[Module[{s$ = 0., p$ = a, i$}, 
         For[i$ = 0, i$ < n, i$++, s$ += foo[p$]; p$ *= a;]; s$]] 
*)
```

As you see we are not finished, because the definition of `foo` was not expanded, but this is not a problem, because we can do it the same way. All this combined with `Compile` gives the above solution.

Comment: Would you care to explain a bit how this works? What is the purpose of `DownValues`?

Comment: @Danvil I have added some information in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! So am I assuming correctly that Mathematica can not compile a recursive function to C? E.g. `f[n_] := If[n == 0, 1, n f[n - 1]]`.

Comment: @Danvil Yes, I discussed this issue several times with e.g. [@Oleksandr R.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r) who has quite some knowledge about such stuff. When I remember correctly, then there is no general way to make a recursive compiled function. This goes along with Leonids answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively).