# CompilationTarget->"C" crashes the kernel

Tags: compile, kernel

**Major deviation from my original post**

I realize that the long code I originally had was very discouraging to debug and did not attract any answers. So I have decided to revamp this question significantly (I hope this is acceptable). Please visit the edit history for older versions of this question.

**Game Plan**

I hypothesize that there are multiple errors in my script the is causing the kernel to crash. But since I can not identify them all at this time, I plan to identify one problem at a time, get solution, implement it in my code and repeat the process of identifying the next problem and posting it on this page, till all the issues are resolved.

**Problem 1.** The following code compiles fine:

```
a=Compile[{{p1,_Real,0},{p2,_Real,0}},Max[0.,Min[p1,10.]-p2],RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}];

b=Compile[{{p1,_Real,0},{p2,_Real,0},{p3,_Real,0},{p4,_Real,0}},
  Max[0.,Min[(20.-p1) 5.-p2-p3,10.]-p4],RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}];

ab=Compile[{{p1,_Real,0},{p2,_Real,0},{p3,_Real,0},{p4,_Real,0},{p5,_Real,0}},
   Min[a[p1,p5],b[p2,p3,p4,p5]],RuntimeAttributes->{Listable},
   CompilationOptions->{"InlineExternalDefinitions"->True}];

f=Compile[{},Module[{k0=Table[0.,{10}]}, ab[k0,k0,k0,k0,k0]],CompilationTarget->"C",
  CompilationOptions->{"InlineExternalDefinitions"->True}];
```

But when I execute `f[]`, the kernel crashes. I am guessing, it is to do with mixing Scalars with Vectors in the `a` and `b` functions. But that is what I thought `Listable` takes care of. Any thoughts?

Comment: As soon as you revert to `MainEvaluate` compilation is of dubious use in any case, correct? Perhaps useful: [Compiling more functions that don't call MainEvaluate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com)./q/24595/131

Comment: Here are two suggestions. (1) Add `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}` (2) Define `f2[x1_Integer, x2_Integer, x3_Integer] := f[x1, x2, x3]` and use `f2` in the call to `NMinimize`. Not sure if these will help but they should at least keep the compiled code from calling on the main evaluator.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, Please look at edit 1. I actually implemented your suggestion 1. Implementing suggestion 2 takes it longer, even though same number of iterations are taken to converge.

Comment: Interesting, the link provided by Yves Klett has a rogue full-stop. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24595/compiling-more-functions-that-dont-call-mainevaluate

Comment: I get 20 seconds with my two suggestions, and it's still running after 2-3 minutes if I omit the second one.

Comment: You state: "When I include CompilationTarget->"C" it does not give any errors, but NMinimize does not work." What actually happened?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Sorry for the delayed response. It is interesting how we both are incurring different results. Implementing your `f2[x1_Integer, x2_Integer, x3_Integer] := f[x1, x2, x3]` with `f2` in `NMinimize` makes it slower on my i5-3210 2.5GHz processor with 6 GB ram computer. without it, and only the code I shown above, it runs quicker. I am confused. With CompilationTarget->"C", the program executes, but does not produce any output (even though I have `Print` in my `EvaluationMonitor`). You can try it too!!

Comment: What I was asking was whether you are sure it executes to completion. In my Linux version it seemingly (and quickly) "does nothing". But in actual fact it crashes the kernel.

Comment: Yes. The `Compile` executes to completion. I use `print` outside `compile` and it prints it. However, it does not execute `NMinimize` properly and terminates without iterating even once. The program does not crash on my windows machine.

Comment: Also, a quick question: I have 38 instances of `CopyTensor` in the above code. Does it mean it holds memory till I close MMA and garbage collection does not kick in? Could this be the reason why the physical memory keeps increasing continuously as I run my program?

Comment: You are doing a considerable amount of array creation, in a `While` loop, so yes, that could account for the memory issues.

Comment: @MichaelE2. Did you use `CompilationTarget->“C”`? Without it, it works, but when I use it in the `compile`, the `kernel` is crashing with `NMinimize`. See @Dan's comments above. He also observed same behavior.

Comment: @MichaelE2. That is too weird...I can not get it to work with `CompilationTarget -> "C"`. Just wanted to make sure: Did you use the above code "as is" or made any improvements? @Dan can you please check if this works for you?

Comment: @MichaelE2. Surprising!! Since we use same version of MMA. I am not sure if it is to do with my Windows 8 and your Mac. Let's see if someone else can validate our results.

Comment: Same problem with _TDM-GCC-4.8.1, Mathematica 8.0.4, Vista 32bit_. Well, in fact it's not the first time I found `CompilationTarget -> "C"` made trouble, but I haven't yet managed to reproduce this kind of problem with a simple enough example for so long.

Comment: @xzczd I have an even simpler case above. check it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a workaround.  Take it as evidence that compilation to C and `Listable` do not always get along.

```
a = Compile[{{p1, _Real, 0}, {p2, _Real, 0}}, 
   Max[0., Min[p1, 10.] - p2]
   (*,RuntimeAttributes -> Listable}*)];

b = Compile[{{p1, _Real, 0}, {p2, _Real, 0}, {p3, _Real, 0}, {p4, _Real, 0}}, 
   Max[0., Min[(20. - p1) 5. - p2 - p3, 10.] - p4]
   (*, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}*)];

ab = Compile[{{p1, _Real, 0}, {p2, _Real, 0}, {p3, _Real, 0},
              {p4, _Real, 0}, {p5, _Real, 0}}, 
      Min[a[p1, p5], b[p2, p3, p4, p5]],
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      CompilationOptions -> {
        "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True,
        "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True (* necessary *)}
     ];

f = Compile[{}, 
   Module[{k0 = Table[0., {10}]}, ab[k0, k0, k0, k0, k0]], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
```

The `Listable` attribute for `a` and `b` are not needed (in this simplified example) since `ab` is `Listable`.  If you get rid of the attribute, the compiled functions can be inlined.  If you don't set `"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True`, the kernel crashes on me.  You might want to look at

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint[f]
```

I take it that the `CompiledFunctionCall` in `f` actually is a call-back to the Virtual Machine (WVM née/né MVM), and not compiled to C.  It may be that an issue in the communication between the C program and the VM leads to the crash.  I do not know the answer to why the crash occurs.

Comment: This is insane. when I implemented your suggestion to remove `Listable` and inlined the upper layer functions in my code, the whole problem is resolved.

Comment: However, it will be interesting to get an insight into why the kernel crashed with the original formulation.

Comment: @brama Yes, it would.  It might take someone with knowledge of how the internals work.