# Using Compile Function Options efficiently

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

While [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively) gives general pointers, I want inputs on **ground rules** for improved performance of nested/interdependent compiled functions.

**sample problem:** 
`a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are four supporting compiled functions that interact among themselves and also support the main function `main`, as defined below:

```
a = Compile[{{p1, _Real}, {p2, _Real}}, Min[p1, p2]];
b = Compile[{{p1, _Real}, {p2, _Real}}, Max[p1, p2]];
c = Compile[{{p1, _Real}, {p2, _Real}}, Min[1, 0.5 + a[p1, p2]/b[p1, p2]], 
       CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},Parallelization -> True];
d = Compile[{{p1, _Real}, {p2, _Real}, {p3, _Real}}, a[Mod[p1, 5] - p2, p3], 
       CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];

main = Compile[{{aa, _Real, 0}}, Module[{
       k1 = RandomReal[10, {10^4, 5}], 
       k2 = RandomReal[5, {10^4, 5}], 
       k3 = RandomReal[15, {10^4, 5}]}, 
       aa + b[k1, k2] + c[k2, k3] + d[k1, k2, k3]], 
       CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];

Do[main[10],{100}];//AbsoluteTiming
```

I found that eliminating redundant options for dependent functions can help improve the performance; e.g. Since `a` and `b` are used in `c` and `c` is defined as listable and parallelized, 1) `a` and `b` need not be defined listable and defining them as listable may deteriorate the performance of `c` (using `AbsoluteTiming`) 2) since `a` and `b` are not defined `listable`, they can be inlined in `c` that will further improve performance, compared to using `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True` alone.

With this understanding I want inputs to help establish ground rules that will enhance the **performance** of main:

1. Which functions need `CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` and why not others?
2. Which functions need `CompilationTarger-> "C"` and why not others?
3. Since `main` calls `b`, `c` and `d` and already has `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True`, none of the supporting functions should need to be listable, but it will not work. Why?
4. What else can be done to improve the performance of `main` (I need to use a compiled function in `NMinimizer`) ?

Comment: Functions `a` and `b` seem redundant, that would simplify matters greatly.

Comment: Also look at inlined compiled functions, not just external definitions, as a compilation option.

Comment: The default way for `Compile` is compilation of your code for Java engine. It is faster than inline code but not the fastest in principle.

`CompilationTarget->"C"` is for the case when you want compile your function as C-code. It is faster the Java code but you need to have C-compiler installed properly in your system.
It will work with any Mathematica function..

Comment: @blochwave As you may have already noticed, `a` and `b` are sample functions defined for demonstration purposes. Which functions would you inline, `c`, `d` and `main` or fewer?

Comment: @Rom38 I understand that. I experienced inconsistent performance when I compile some/all the functions to C (possibly because C-compiler may not be installed properly). So I was wondering if there are some guidelines for use of `CompilationTarget->"C"` for nested functions calls.

Comment: If you're compiling `a, b, c & d`, then add the inline option to, in your example, the functions that call other functions. So `c, d & main`.

Comment: @blochwave. My bad, but `main` can not be inlined because `c` and `d` are listable. But I agree inlining `c` and `d` will improve `AbsoluteTiming` of `main`.

Comment: @brama, did you try C-compilation for other more simple examples (without nested functions)? Does it make evident speed up?

As I see, the `CompilationTarget->"C"` could be used for all compilable functions without additional conditions. 
All rest attributes can make some parasitic effects on performance due to their inner "interference"

Comment: @Rom38 for simple functions similar to `a` and `b`, I do not see any improvement with `CompilationTarget->"C"`

Comment: @Rom38 "The default way for Compile is compilation of your code for Java engine." Is that true?  I thought Compile produces Mathematica bytecode which is faster than the usual interpreter but still inside Mathematica.  So far as I am aware Compile never generates java; source or bytecode. I'm happy to be proved wrong if you can point at some docs.

Comment: @Ymareth, As I understood from the Wolfram's description, compilation means my default namely creation of a code for evaluation on Java-engine.

Comment: @Rom38 Could you link to the section in the documentation you're referring to?

Comment: @Ymareth Hm, in curent version of documentation I've seen just [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compile/tutorial/CompilationTarget.html#681478883) There is a phrase: _The default setting is , which creates code for the traditional Wolfram Language virtual machine_
Previously this section had some words about Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### 1. Optimising the code given

So I've completely rewritten my answer to this optimization, after [@brama](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11116/brama) pointed out my versions returned a scalar rather than a matrix - my mistake, apologies.

First recall the performance of [@brama](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11116/brama)'s code:

```
Do[main[10], {100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 1.10 seconds *)
```

But what if we compile [@brama](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11116/brama)'s `main` function to C, like I've done? Well, on my computer it takes about the same amount of time as it does compiled to MVM.

So here's my version:

```
main2 = Compile[{{aa, _Real, 0}}, 
    Module[{
     k1 = RandomReal[10, {10^4, 5}],
     k2 = RandomReal[5, {10^4, 5}],
     k3 = RandomReal[15, {10^4, 5}]},
    10 + Max @@ {k1, k2}
       + Map[Min[1., #] &, 
          0.5 + MapThread[Min, {k2, k3}, 2]/MapThread[Max, {k2, k3}, 2], {-1}]
       + MapThread[Min, {(Mod[#, 5] & /@ k1) - k2, k3}, 2]
    ], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

Do[main2[10], {100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.37 seconds *)

(* Check it outputs a matrix, not a scalar *)
main2[10]

(*{{18.8678, 22.1486, 20.0878, 20.6308, 17.7006},
 ...9998...,
 {22.5947, 19.6328, 22.6912, 19.3589, 18.1205}}*)
```

Nearly a 3x speed-up!

One last sanity check (although all the functions I've used are in here [List of compilable functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions))

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[main2]
(* No calls to MainEvaluate, no instances of CopyTensor *)
```

So it's a good compilation. By constrast, the original code in [@brama](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11116/brama)'s `main` returns a few instances of `CompiledFunctionCall`, which could impact on performance.

**Comparison with the uncompiled version**

What happens if you don't compile to C, but to MVM instead? Well my version takes about 1.2 seconds, so  that isn't great. And what about the MMA-only version?

```
uncompiledMain[num_] := Module[{
   k1 = RandomReal[10, {10^4, 5}],
   k2 = RandomReal[5, {10^4, 5}],
   k3 = RandomReal[15, {10^4, 5}]},
  num + Max @@ {k1, k2} + 
   Map[Min[1., #] &, 
    0.5 + MapThread[Min, {k2, k3}, 2]/
      MapThread[Max, {k2, k3}, 2], {-1}] +
   MapThread[Min, {(Mod[#, 5] & /@ k1) - k2, k3}, 2]
  ];

Do[uncompiledmain[10], {100}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 11.51 seconds *)
```

Considerably slower. So compilation all the way to C is useful for my implementation, but not useful for yours.

**Larger matrices**

What about with larger matrices `{k1, k2, k3}`?

```
(* Update definitions of k1, k2 and k3 to *)
{
 k1 = RandomReal[10, {10^7, 5}],
 k2 = RandomReal[5, {10^7, 5}],
 k3 = RandomReal[15, {10^7, 5}]
}

main[10]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 5.58 seconds *)

main2[10]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 4.75 seconds *)
```

So the speed-up is a bit smaller here. I wonder why?

**Further analysis**

Interesting things happen when we take `{k1,k2,k3}` out of the compiled function.

```
bramasMain = Compile[{{aa, _Real, 0}, {k1, _Real, 2}, {k2, _Real,2}, {k3, _Real, 2}}, 
    Module[{},aa + b[k1, k2] + c[k2, k3] + d[k1, k2, k3]],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
  ];

blochwavesMain = Compile[{{aa, _Real, 0}, {k1, _Real, 2}, {k2, _Real, 2}, {k3, _Real,2}}, 
Module[{}, 10 + Max @@ {k1, k2} + 
    Map[Min[1., #] &, 
     0.5 + MapThread[Min, {k2, k3}, 2]/
       MapThread[Max, {k2, k3}, 2], {-1}] +
    MapThread[Min, {(Mod[#, 5] & /@ k1) - k2, k3}, 2]
   ], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ];
```

First, it allows us to check the two functions are equivalent, as both receive the same set of random numbers.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 externalk1 = RandomReal[10, {10^7, 5}];
 externalk2 = RandomReal[5, {10^7, 5}];
 externalk3 = RandomReal[15, {10^7, 5}];
]
(* 1.59 seconds *)

AbsoluteTiming[result1 = bramasMain[10, externalk1, externalk2, externalk3];]
(* 4.29 seconds *)

AbsoluteTiming[result2 = blochwavesMain[10, externalk1, externalk2, externalk3];]
(* 3.24 seconds *)

result1 == result2
(* True *)

Norm[result1 - result2]
(* 0. *)
```

What about if we compile `bramasMain` to C?

```
bramasMainC = Compile[{{aa, _Real, 0}, {k1, _Real, 2}, {k2, _Real,2}, {k3, _Real, 2}}, 
    Module[{},aa + b[k1, k2] + c[k2, k3] + d[k1, k2, k3]],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True},
   CompilationTarget = "C"
  ];

AbsoluteTiming[result3 = bramasMainC[10, externalk1, externalk2, externalk3];]
(* 5.01 seconds *)
```

Compiling to C is now slower! Why is this? It's likely that the `CompiledFunctionCall`s found when you do `CompilePrint[bramasMainC]` are indeed affecting the performance, because the functions `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` aren't inlined. It would seem to me that when compiling only to MVM rather than C, the overhead with the `CompiledFunctionCall` is less.

---

### 2. Your questions

Returning to your questions in the original post, these were:

> 1. Which functions need `CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"}` and why not others?
> 2. Which functions need `CompilationTarget -> "C"` and why not others?
> 3. Since `main` calls `b`, `c` and `d` and already has `RuntimeAttributes -> Listable}, Parallelization -> True`, none of the supporting functions should need to be listable, but it will not work. Why?
> 4. What else can be done to improve the performance of `main` (I need to use a compiled function in `NMinimize`)?

**Q1.** I'll attempt to answer this.

Regarding `ExpressionOptimization`, [from the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompilationOptions.html)

> If the compiled function needs to make an external call to the Wolfram
>   Language, the default setting (for `ExpressionOptimization`) of `Automatic` does not optimize

In an ideal world, you want to minimize any external calls in a compiled function. Therefore, if you have no external calls, the default setting is sufficient. Otherwise you need to set it to `True` **and then compare the performance with the default setting to see if it is beneficial.**

Regarding `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`, [again look at the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuntimeOptions.html), you need to consider what this option actually means, and if you are putting speed before quality in a critical section of your code (e.g. catching overflow). Focus on this first before speed.

**Q2. & Q3.** Hopefully someone might chip in here.

Regarding the instruction to compile to C, this is complex. Notice that in my analysis above, when I compiled to C and found your function ran slower, I only had `"CompilationTarget" -> "C"` inside the `main` function, not in `c` or `d`. If you compile `c` and `d` to C as well, there is a modest speed-up, but (about 20% or so), but because the functions are inlined, there is still the problem with the `CompiledFunctionCall`s.

**Q4.** Is this actually the function you want to use?

If it isn't (and `main` is in fact more complex), my suggestion would be to optimize it as far as you are able, and if the performance is still not what you want, post a question here with your **actual** function asking for pointers about optimization. For example, compiling to C might be beneficial there, and that confuses matters when it comes to your actual problem, since as we've seen compiling to C doesn't always improve performance.

This makes sense in response to your statement:

> I want inputs on ground rules for improved performance of
>   nested/interdependent compiled functions.

As the sample problem shows, it's not quite so simple. I've managed to turn your nested functions into a single compilable function with a sometimes significant speed-up, with no need for listable behaviour in the compilation options.

This may well be the case with your real problem. So focus on your actual function and problem-at-hand, and remember the community is here to help!

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. However, note that the output of main and main2 are different. While the former gives a matrix, the latter gives a scalar. This is because, without `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` `a` and `b` will give scalars, which is not the desired output. Therefore, as you suggested I could make `c`, `d`, and `main` listable (which means `a` and `b` are listable) and inline `c` and `d`(Note that I can not inline `main` because `c` and `d` are listable; see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54459/11116). But I found that inlining is less effecient than my `main`

Comment: There's a way round this (thanks for pointing out the error) - I'll get back to you.

Comment: @brama is this update any better?