# Compile a MeijerG function

Tags: warning-messages, special-functions, compile

I am not very experienced with `Compile`, I tried to use it for a Meijer-G function

```
mTest = Compile[{{k, _Integer}, {b, _Real}}, MeijerG[{{1/2, 1/2}, {}}, {{0, 1/2, k}, {-k}}, b^2], {{MeijerG[_, _, _], _Real}}]
```

but it returns the error

```
CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.
```

Does it mean that I can't `Compile` `MeijerG` or is there a trick to it. Eventually I would like to `Compile` a long calculation that contains a few Meijer-G functions.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't compile `MeijerG`. See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) for a list of compilable functions.

Comment: So `Compile` can't accelerate the evaluation of `MeijerG`. However you can precompute it in different points and use `Interpolation`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason you get a message is because `Compile` cannot handle non tensor arrays, and the first argument to `MeijerG` is not a tensor (i.e. `{{1/2, 1/2}, {}}`).

Now DumpsterDoofus is correct in that `MeijerG` cannot be compiled, but we can get around this error, which will make `MeijerG` *usable* in compiled code. What I mean by usable is `Compile` will call Mathematica's main kernel to evaluate your `MeijerG` expression, and then jump right back into the compiled code. This is much better than the current behavior, where the non tensor causes `Compile` to jump out and not return.

```
Mei[m_, n_, p_, q_, args___, x_] := MeijerG[{{args}[[1;;n]], {args}[[n+1;;p]]}, {{args}[[p+1;;p+m]], {args}[[p+m+1;;-1]]}, x]

mTest = Compile[{{k, _Integer}, {b, _Real}}, Mei[3, 2, 2, 4, 0.5,0.5,0, 0.5,k , -k, b^2]]

mTest[3, 2.3]
```

> ```
> 1.27871
> ```

Comment: I was just wondering whether it is possible to 'break' the MeijerG function down to a series of elementary calculations that can be compiled. I have no idea how Mathematica computes it, but I got this idea while reading [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24596/18695)