# Compiled function without MainEvaluate

Tags: compile

My question is related to this thread here:

[Compiling more functions that don't call MainEvaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24595/compiling-more-functions-that-dont-call-mainevaluate)

Within the thread it is suggested to use pure functions and then the option `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` to avoid calls of `MainEvalute`.

But how can one avoid `MainEvalute` if one wants to call a function in the iteration limits of a table within `Compile[]`. E.g. something like

```
g = #^2 &;
f = # + 1 &;

compiledFunction = 
  Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}}, Table[g[x], {n, f[1], 2}], 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];

CompilePrint[compiledFunction]
```

returns

```
        1 argument
        11 Integer registers
        4 Real registers
        1 Tensor register
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        I6 = 0
        I2 = 2
        I7 = -1
        I0 = 1
        Result = T(R1)0

1   I3 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[f][ I0]]
2   I4 = IteratorCountI[ I3, I2]]
3   I5 = I6
4   I8 = Subtract[ I4, I7]
5   T(R1)0 = Table[ I8]
6   I9 = I7
7   goto 12
8   I10 = I3 + I9
9   R1 = R0
10  R3 = Square[ R1]
11  Element[ T(R1)0, I5] = R3
12  if[ ++ I9 <= I4] goto 8
13  Return
```

and calls `MainEvaluate`. Is it possible to call externally defined functions within the `Compile` environment to use them as upper or lower boundary of an iteration within `Table[]` without calling `MainEvaluate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you can use

```
With[{f = f, g = g},
 fc1 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}}, Table[g[x], {n, f[1], 2}]];
]
```

or

```
Function[{f, g},
  fc2 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}}, Table[g[x], {n, f[1], 2}]]
][f, g]
```

which both lead to a full inclusion of your definitions.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @DisplayName In some cases you may also call `Evaluate` on the body of the compileable function, i.e. `Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}}, Evaluate[Table[g[x], {n, f[1], 2}]]]` In your toy example this would result in `Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}}, {x^2}]`